# How to Split test-names and log-details from given text file using python groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7

From the following input file i wanted to split `testname` and associated `logdetails`

**Input file:**

```
2/1/1/2/tasdf.c:

LOG:
        backslash-newline should be deleted before tokenizing
    No diagnostics line
RESULT: 2/1/1/2/tasdf.c                                          FAILED

----------------------------------------
2/1/1/2/tlasdf.c:

LOG:
+++ stderr ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
tlasdf.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '_t'
    t x[] = L\
    ^
ls: cannot access '*.o': No such file or directory
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    | T | Translation Phases | 2 | \\ | L | 2 |
    Compilation failed
RESULT: 2/1/1/2/tlasdf.c                                          FAILED

----------------------------------------
2/2/4/1/texasdfgen(0):

LOG:
    511 external identifiers in one source file
    Compilation failed ungracefully
RESULT: 2/2/4/1/textasdf.gen                                    FAILED
```

**code used to split:**

```
import re
import sys

#inputfile
TEST = sys.argv[1]

#Open input file and match testname
def testname(FILE):
    testlist=[]
    for line in open(FILE, 'r+'):
        match1 = re.search(r'.*\.c\:$|.*\.gen\(\d+\)\:$', line)
        if match1:
            testname = match1.group(0)
            testlist.append(testname)
    return(testlist)

#Open input file and match log details
def logdetail(FILE):
array = []
with open(TEST) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('LOG:'):
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith('RESULT:'):
                    break
             # else process lines from section
                array.append(line)
print(array)    
testname = testname(TEST)
for test in testname:
    print (test)        

loddetails = logdetail1(TEST)
for log in loddetails:
    print(log)
```

`testname` prints correctly and logdetails are present in array but how to club `testname` associated with `logdetails`.

**Output from current code:**

```
2/1/1/2/tasdf.c:
2/1/1/2/tlasdf.c:
2/2/4/1/tiasdf.gen(0):
['backslash-newline should be deleted before tokenizing', 'No diagnostics line', '+++ stderr ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++', "tlasdf.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '_t'", 't x[] = L\\', '^', "ls: cannot access '*.o': No such file or directory", '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++', '| T | Translation P
hases | 2 | \\\\ | L | 2 |', 'Compilation failed', '511 external identifiers in one source file', 'Compilation failed ungracefully', '8 nesting levels of #include files', 'Compilation failed ungracefully']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2/1/1/2/tasdf.c:            backslash-newline should be deleted before tokenizing No diagnostics line
2/1/1/2/tlasdf.c:           +++ stderr ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++tlex2.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 't'
2/2/4/1/textasdf.gen(0):    511 external identifiers in one source file  Compilation failed ungracefully
```

(Actually my final expected output is to print into excel sheet as mentioned in screen shot)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CVGu.png)

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clear?

Comment: Its good to see your current output, but what about including the expected output? Then its easier to see where your going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do the follwoing modification to `logdetail()`:

```
def logdetail(FILE):
    collect = False
    array = []
    current = []
    with open(FILE, 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('LOG:'):
                collect = True
            else:
                if line.startswith('RESULT: '):
                    collect = False
                    array.append(current)
                    current=[]
                if collect:
                    current.append(line.strip())

    return(array)
```

Then use this to print (assuming always `len(testname) = len(logdetails)`)

```
testname = testname(TEST)
loddetails = logdetail1(TEST)
for test in testname:
    print (test + '\t' +  " ".join(logdetail1[testname.index(test)]))
```

Comment: or this for styling: `print ("{:<25}  {}".format(test," ".join(loddetails[testname.index(test)])))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a dictionary base on your results and fill your excel file directly by using the keys & values of this dictionary.

You need to modify your logdetail() function a bit as follows:

```
def extract_data(path_to_file):
    try:
        in_file = open(path_to_file, "r")
        text = in_file.read()
        in_file.close()
        if text == '':
            return False
    except Exception as exception:
        raise
    return text

def logdetail(TEXT):
    array = []
    Temporary = ''
    for line in TEXT:  
        if 'LOG:' in line:
            pass
        else:
            if 'RESULT:' in line:
                array.append('LOG:'+Temporary)
                Temporary= ''
                continue
            Temporary+=line
    return array
```

then make a dictionary using your functions results:

```
BIG_TEXT = extract_data(path_to_file)
loddetails = logdetail(BIG_TEXT.strip().split('\n'))
testnames = testname(TEST)

Merge = {}
for each in testnames:
   try:
      Merge[each] = loddetails[testnames.index(each)]
   except ValueError:
      Merge[each] = 'Not Given'
```

Note that that you can skip function extract_data() and just pass your file's contents.

At the end you can call your dictionary keys() for your first excel column and values() for the second excel column.

**Edit:**
To write this dictionary to an excel file, and based on your attached screen shot:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\Desktop\data.xlsx') # Create an excel file
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
for key, value in Merge.items():
    row += 1 ; col = 0
    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    worksheet.write(row, col+1, value)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: thank you @Ssein, I'm new to python. Could you please help me how can i use dictionary keys() and values() to add it to excel?

Comment: @coder Check out the **Edit**, first you should install `xlsxwriter` package in **cmd**